# How to merge layers into a single QgsVectorLayer?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, merge, qgis-2.8

I have a set of different layers (and their respective shapefiles) with information of electric lines. All the layers have the same Fields in their Attribute Tables, but contain information about different features. I want to merge only the layers that I choose and save them into a new QgsVectorLayer (Or something similar).

To get all of the layers, I'm using this:

```
    lyrs = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
```

And I want to get something like:

```
    new_layer=lyrs[1]+lyrs[3]
    new_layer.getFeatures() #Do something else from here, but is irrelevant to the question
```

(Obviously that last part won't work because *"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QgsVectorLayer' and 'QgsVectorLayer'"*, but that is the idea of what I need to get)

Some details:

1: I would prefer a method that does not create a new shapefile like "qgis:mergevectorlayers" (The method will be called multiple times, and it would create a lot of unnecesary shapefiles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a [Memory Provider](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider) would suite your needs as

> It does not store data on disk, allowing developers to use it as a fast backend for some temporary layers.

Based on your descriptions and the linked example from the cookbook I created some code. It is not fully tested and maybe you will have to tweak it a little:

```
lyrs = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()

fields = lyrs[1].pendingFields()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "temporary_lines", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

for f in fields:
  pr.addAttributes([f])

vl.updateFields()

feats1 = lyr[1].getFeatures()
for feature in feats1:
  pr.addFeatures([feature])

feats3 = lyr[3].getFeatures()
for feature in feats3:
  pr.addFeatures([feature])

vl.updateExtents()

# Do something with it
```

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer @bennos . I will accept it as soon as I can test it, but it looks like what I'm looking for.